# %20 in my Url in ASP.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have such Url: `/%20Account/%20LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f+Admin%2f+Index`

I have two questions:

1)Why I have `%20` before `Account` and `LogOn`? Is it something like spaces?

2)How to remove `%20` before `Account` and `LogOn`?

Maybe something wrong with Routes?

It's my class RegisterRoutes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            null, 
            "", 
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List",category = (string)null,page=1 }) ;

        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "Page{page}", 
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List",category = (string)null });

        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{category}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 });

        routes.MapRoute(
           null,
           "{category}/Page{page}",
           new { controller = "Product", action = "List"});

        routes.MapRoute(null, " {controller}/ {action}");

    }
```

Comment: Show your `web.config`.

Comment: Beacause your url contains `white space` between words

Comment: spaces are encoded as `%20` in the url

Comment: @RasoolGhafari white space?

Comment: Side note: [white space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(computer_science)) is more commonly used as name of group of all characters that represent some sort of empty space in text. `%20` is %-encoding of most common "space" (Unicode code point U+0020, or ASCII 0x20).

Answer (score 1):

Because your url contains **white space** between words,

For example when you enter this ('**somesite.com/some thing**') address in your browser, your browser encode that address to **'somesite.com/some%20thing'**

then to decode your `URL` in code behind, you can use `Server.UrlDecode("someURL")`

Answer (score 1):

> 1)Why I have %20 before Account and LogOn? Is it something like
>   spaces?

This is because you have space inside the URL string. Those are converted into encoded string which for the same is %20

> 2)How to remove %20 before Account and LogOn?

You need to create a link without a space before Account and LogOn. If you are using Html Helper to create the link, you may have not noticed a space before the string of the action.

Answer (score 0):

1) That is the encoded `URL`.

2) Not sure in what context you are using it but you can decode it using `Server.UrlDecode("string")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my application, where %20 appears at the end of the url. I had to use .Trim() in order to remove the space before I pass in the required id.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID_NO.Trim()})
```

and that solved my problem.

Comment: for some reason "item.ID_NO" had some space after it, I have no idea how it got there yet. in the meanwhile, this solution worked.